# How can I have a user enter javascript code into angular form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing

I would like to allow the user to write javascript code into an angular form and run some mocha/chai tests on that code.... I am looking for ideas to go about it...should I parse the code from the form pass that string to a function? Any ideas please...any repo already doing that with angular...

The user should be able to write a javascript function that does some tasks and then the app should run a test on it to make sure the javascript entered in the form does the tasks that we asked...

```
ValidateEnteredCode(jsCodeEntered: string) {

  If   (  This.unitTest(jscodeentered)  ) {
      this.snackBar("good job, your function works as.    
      required")
  }

}
```

Comment: Why is there an `If` and `This` in your code?

Comment: Well the idea is to test the form input with a mocha test so if the test pass the user will get a positive feedback

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear, those keywords are case-sensitive. They need to be `if` and `this` instead.

Comment: why don't you configure your application in a way that giving input from command line will do the job. the running script like npm start npm test.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather recommend searching for existing modules/libraries which provide the capability to develop your own code editor.

To begin with, you can check the following two references.

Article using ace code editor
https://medium.com/@ofir3322/create-an-online-ide-with-angular-6-nodejs-part-1-163a939a7929

Monaco editor (Powers Microsoft VS Code)
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Node module for Monaco Editor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-monaco-editor

**Unit test runtime**

Then check the frameworks like mocha which give you capability to unit test code at runtime.

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-Mocha-programmatically